# Django not accepting parsed csv date input even though it follows the YYYY-MM-DD format. What is the problem?

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm trying to populate my existing Django model with values from a csv file. I've tried to use datetime.strptime() but it also has not worked.

This is the code I'm trying to run from the Django python manage.py shell
**loadcsv.py**

```
import csv
from dashboard.models import Checkin
with open('foo.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_reader:
        new_checkin = Checkin(date=row[0],project_id=row[1],manager_id=row[2],user_id=row[3],hours=row[4])
        new_checkin.save()
        # # row[0] = date;
        # # row[1] = project
        # # row[2] = manager
        # # row[3] = user
        # # row[4] = hours
```

**models.py** (dashboard.models)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Checkin(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    project_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    manager_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

**foo.csv** sample entry

```
date,project_id,manager_id,user_id,hours
2019-09-11,134,1,1,3
2019-09-11,201,1,1,5
2019-12-23,14,8,2,0.46
2019-12-23,14,8,2,0.46
```

**The error I'm getting**

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“date” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']
```

I can save to the database when I manually create a single object in the shell like so:

```
from dashboard.models import Checkin

new_checkin = Checkin(date="2012-01-01", manager_id="5", project_id="5",user_id="3", hours="0.75")
new_checkin.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip headers while reading csv. Django is complaining about the header “date” which is not in date format.
You can use either next or DictReader to skip headers.

Comment: Thank you, fixed it with "next(csv_reader)" before the for loop.